# Google JS API oAuth Callback

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

For an application I'm working on, I need to get a `refresh_token` from Google over OAuth2. The flow is pretty clear to me, we'll probably be using the [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) gem. While investigating, I noticed that the Google API loader script takes a callback as a get-variable in the URL (see snippet below). Since this is part of a bigger SPA, and I'd rather not expose this as a global (also, we're using RequireJS), is there any way to run this code within my controller?

Snippet in Github:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plus.js?onload=gpAsyncInit',
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: true
  });
});

window.gpAsyncInit = function() {
  // api is ready
};
```

Preferred:

```
SomeController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plus.js?onload=this.showView', // I'm aware this clearly doesn't work as is, just an example
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: true
      })
    },
    showView: function(){
      // api is ready
    }
});
```

Any advice here? Is this even possible?

Comment: you can't get a refresh token from Javascript. Incidentally, f you only want oauth, you could use the auth only client "auth.js". To your question, it mostly depends on your framework, but as a last resort you could have the callback set a global boolean which your controller is polling for on a setTimeout

Comment: I'm aware of that, we'll make an AJAX to our own back-end to fetch the token. I just wanna know if there's a way of knowing when the API is loaded without resorting to globals. I'm not sure what the reasoning behind that is, but I think it's an unbelievably ugly way of indicating 'ready'.

Comment: if you're fetching the access token from your own server, what will you be using the google client js for? In my experience, the only thing it's worth using for is OAuth. All other google API access is much better dealt with with raw XHR, or using the features of your JS framework (in my case AngularJS). I see where you're going with the question, but since I don't use require.js (I'm straight angularJs), not much more I can add.